# Partition function $Z$ and number of microstates $\Omega(E)$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

How is the number of microstates $\Omega (E)$ related to the partition function $Z$? I know the mathematical relationship. I want to know the physical interpretation.

My understanding is that $\Omega (E)$ represents the number of microstates of a system with a given fixed energy $E$ and the partition function $Z$ represents the number of microstates for all possible values of $E$ of the system. Am I correct or missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the notation $\Omega(E)$ signifies the *number* of microstates with energy $E$. On the other hand, the partition function $Z$ is mostly conveniently described as a sum over microstates such that the probability $p_i$ of being in a state of energy $E_i$ is,

$$p_i = \frac{e^{-\beta E_i}}{Z}.$$

We can think of $\Omega(E_i)$ as being a degeneracy factor when we consider the partition function,

$$Z = \sum_{\{E_i\}} \Omega(E_i)e^{-\beta E_i}$$

so as to properly count all states, even those with possibly the same $E_i$. The partition function itself though does not represent a number. You wrote,

> ... the partition function $Z$ represents the number of microstates for all possible values of $E$...

which I interpret as,

$$\sum_{\{E_i\}} \Omega(E_i) \neq Z$$

which is clearly not the definition of the partition function. However, we could possibly recover this from the partition function. Writing $\Omega(E_i) = \Omega_i$, if the limit,

$$\lim_{\beta \to 0} \Omega_i e^{-\beta E_i}$$

exists and $\sum_i \Omega_i e^{-\beta E_i}$ converges uniformly, then the limit and summation may be exchanged by the dominated convergence theorem, and we have that the total number of microstates,

$$\sum_{i} \Omega_i = \lim_{\beta \to 0} Z(\beta).$$

Comment: In the last part can you explain physically how at high temperature number of microstates $\Omega(E)$ is equal to $Z$?. Mathematically i understood. I am not able to get what actually is the partition function?

Comment: @ManishSahu Look at the two sums; if $\beta=0$ then the exponential is just one and all that is left is the sum over $\Omega$. So providing you can exchange the limit and summation you can simply take the limit of the partition function.

Comment: @ManishSahu I would argue the partition function as an object on its own has no direct physical meaning, it is a mathematical tool. That being said there are links to the notion of effective actions and free energy, where we can prescribe a more physical meaning.